# cypress-select-test or any other way of segregating smoke, regression test cases in cypress?

Tags: mocha.js, cypress

Does anyone use cypress-select-tests or any other way of segregating smoke, regression test cases in cypress?
I have used cypress-select-tests to tag my test cases but found out that it is first scanning all the test cases and later marked them as pending/non-executed test cases and finally it runs the tagged test cases.

Comment: What's the desired behaviour for your context?

Comment: It should run only tagged cases rather than scanning all the test cases at first and then running the tagged test cases. Say I have 200 test cases and i tagged two test cases. I shouldn't wait for 200 test cases to scan it (it's time consuming)should directly run tagged test cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
**use.only before the test case.**
  describe("suite",() => {
     it.only("test case1",() => {})
     it("test case2",() => {})
     it.only("test case3",() => {})
  })
 **it will run only test case1 and 3 only remaining test cases will sort out.**
```